# Nyquist–Shannon Sampling Theorem Counter Example?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, signal-processing, sampling

I was learning about the Nyquist theorem regards signal processing the area of interest which I will rephrase below:

Given a signal lasting infinitely long with a maximum frequency of f, then you can always replicate the signal perfectly by sampling by AT LEAST 2f.

However I quickly thought up what seemed to be a counter example which I cannot shake off:

---

Take a sine signal of frequency of 1Hz. This is the only frequency of such a wave so according to the theorem I can replicate the signal as long as I sample at 2Hz intervals. A valid set of samples would be to sample at every point the signal crosses the x axis which is sampling at 2f satisfying the condition. (At 0 amplitude)

This gives 0 for every sample. However this tells you nothing about the signal - it could be the flat signal of 0 amplitude, the same sine wave of double or half amplitude. Hence this seems to be a counter example to the theorem suggesting the same frequency needs to be greater than 2f.

---

Could someone please either explain the theorem (It may be I am misunderstanding the theorem) or confirm this counter example.

Thanks!

Comment: The theorem requires that sampling be at a rate larger than twice the maximum frequency in the signal. At exactly twice the maximum frequency, we run into the issue that you have noted. You are by no means the first to have discovered this issue.  For example, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist–Shannon_sampling_theorem) says "Modern statements of the theorem are sometimes careful to explicitly state that $x(t)$ must contain no sinusoidal component at exactly frequency $B$, or that $B$ must be _strictly less_ than $\frac 12$ the sample rate." (emphasis added)

Comment: Thanks - The place I was learning this made no mention and I was looking around and was struggling to find a reference to the issue. Thank you. :) Sorry rep too low to upvote your comment. :(